# VBA If Statement within For (Else Running even when If condition is met)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm pretty new to VBA and having issues with a Else statements running even when If conditions are met.

Pretty sure this is due to the If statement being within a For & Next

```
For iCnt = 1 To Len(Firstname)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(Firstname, iCnt, 1)) Then
        MsgBox "The Firstname cannot contain Numeric values"
    ElseIf Len(Firstname) > 100 Then
        MsgBox "The Firstname exceeds the character limit (100)"
    Else
        Sheet3.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.Firstname.Value
    End If
Next iCnt
```

Please any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Place the cursor on the `For` keyword, press F9 to toggle a breakpoint, then run your code. When the breakpoint is hit, press F8 to run the code line by line, and you'll find that the `For` loop has nothing to do with it... and that this `ElseIf` condition makes no sense inside this loop body ;-)

Comment: Because you are in a For loop, else will be called if any of the characters in Firstname is a letter and the length is not over 100. This is not what you want (I suspect). You need to change your logic.

Answer (score 3):

Really you only want the first condition to exist in that FOR loop. The rest of it should be tested afterwards and only if that first condition never trips.

Consider instead:

```
Dim nameHasNumbers as boolean: nameHasNumbers = False
For iCnt = 1 To Len(Firstname)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(Firstname, iCnt, 1)) Then
        'number found toggle flag and exit the loop
        nameHasNumbers = True
        exit For
    End If    
Next iCnt

'Now alert the user or update the name cell
If nameHasNumbers Then
    MsgBox "The Firstname cannot contain Numeric values"
ElseIf Len(Firstname) > 100 Then
    MsgBox "The Firstname exceeds the character limit (100)"
Else
    Sheet3.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.Firstname.Value
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

For each letter in the name you are going to get the Else to happen. Need to restructure the whole thing. I would put the checking into a function and then based on that result do your other work. If you need a message to inform the user of the reason for the name being invalid add that to the function. Your function can then do other testing on other conditions without affecting your calling code.

```
Private Function IsValidName(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    If Len(value) > 100 Then
        IsValidName = False
        Exit Function
    Else
        Dim charCounter As Long
        For charCounter = 1 To Len(value)
            If IsNumeric(Mid(value, charconter, 1)) Then
                IsValidName = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        IsValidName = True
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to check whether a string includes a digit, you can compare it to a `Like` pattern which matches a digit: `FirstName Like "*[0-9]*"`

That approach is simpler than looping through the string checking whether each character is a digit.  And since it does not require the `For` loop, it should be easier to avoid the logic error in your code sample.  (As long as the string length did not exceed 100 characters, it wrote a value to `Sheet3.Cells(lRow, 2).Value` again for each and every non-numeric character contained in `FirstName`.)

```vb
If FirstName Like "*[0-9]*" Then
    MsgBox "The Firstname cannot contain Numeric values"
ElseIf Len(FirstName) > 100 Then
    MsgBox "The Firstname exceeds the character limit (100)"
Else
    Sheet3.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.FirstName.Value
End If
```